# Graph construction method optimization

Tags: graphs-and-networks

This is a problem of algorithm improvement for speed. The context is of graph construction, it derives from trying to deal with some imperfectly prepared Open Street Map data.

I have a set of individual edges that I need to connect together to form the complete graph. I have a method which works and is OK for smaller networks, I’m looking for a way to improve its speed since I need to deal with cases of 10^5 or more edges.

Here's a small example. The following is the set of individual edges:

```
edges0 = {1 -> 2, 3 -> 4, 5 -> 6, 7 -> 8, 9 -> 10, 11 -> 12, 13 -> 14, 15 -> 16, 17 -> 18, 19 -> 20, 21 -> 22, 23 -> 24, 25 -> 26, 27 -> 28, 29 -> 30, 31 -> 32, 33 -> 34, 35 -> 36, 37 -> 38, 39 -> 40, 41 -> 42, 43 -> 44, 45 -> 46, 47 -> 48, 49 -> 50, 51 -> 52, 53 -> 54, 55 -> 56, 57 -> 58, 59 -> 60}
```

These are the set of shared vertices:

```
shared = {2 -> 25, 3 -> 48, 3 -> 49, 5 -> 44, 5 -> 45, 7 -> 50, 7 -> 51, 8 -> 58, 8 -> 59, 9 -> 52, 9 -> 53, 11 -> 42, 11 -> 43, 13 -> 34, 13 -> 35, 15 -> 22, 15 -> 23, 17 -> 28, 17 -> 29, 19 -> 36, 19 -> 37, 20 -> 26, 20 -> 27, 22 -> 15, 22 -> 23, 23 -> 15, 23 -> 22, 24 -> 40, 24 -> 41, 25 -> 2, 26 -> 20, 26 -> 27, 27 -> 20, 27 -> 26,  28 -> 17, 28 -> 29, 29 -> 17, 29 -> 28, 30 -> 32, 30 -> 33, 32 -> 30, 32 -> 33, 33 -> 30, 33 -> 32, 34 -> 13, 34 -> 35, 35 -> 13, 35 -> 34, 36 -> 19, 36 -> 37, 37 -> 19, 37 -> 36, 38 -> 54, 38 -> 55, 40 -> 24, 40 -> 41, 41 -> 24, 41 -> 40, 42 -> 11, 42 -> 43, 43 -> 11, 43 -> 42, 44 -> 5, 44 -> 45, 45 -> 5, 45 -> 44, 46 -> 47, 46 -> 57, 47 -> 46, 47 -> 57, 48 -> 3, 48 -> 49, 49 -> 3, 49 -> 48, 50 -> 7, 50 -> 51, 51 -> 7, 51 -> 50, 52 -> 9, 52 -> 53, 53 -> 9, 53 -> 52, 54 -> 38, 54 -> 55, 55 -> 38, 55 -> 54, 57 -> 46, 57 -> 47, 58 -> 8, 58 -> 59, 59 -> 8, 59 -> 58}
```

**shared** is the set of vertices that are connected and also equivalent (at the same location in space), therefore one of them can "compacted" into the other). For example 2 and 25 are at the same location, so 25 can be replaced with 2 and so on for the rest of the list. This way a set of replacement rules can be constructed that when applied to the combined set of **edges0** and shared is reduced (or compacted) into minimal set of edges.

The method I use to accomplish this is as follows:

```
drules = Reap[NestWhile[ DeleteDuplicates[Rest[#] /. Sow[Rule @@ Reverse[First[#]]]] &, 
 shared, Length[#] > 0 &]][[2, 1]] // DeleteCases[Rule[x_, x_]]
```

(* {25 -> 2, 48 -> 3, 49 -> 3, 44 -> 5, 45 -> 5, 50 -> 7, 51 -> 7,
58 -> 8, 59 -> 8, 52 -> 9, 53 -> 9, 42 -> 11, 43 -> 11, 34 -> 13,
35 -> 13, 22 -> 15, 23 -> 15, 28 -> 17, 29 -> 17, 36 -> 19, 37 -> 19,
26 -> 20, 27 -> 20, 40 -> 24, 41 -> 24, 32 -> 30, 33 -> 30,
54 -> 38, 55 -> 38, 47 -> 46, 57 -> 46} *)

The graph can then be constructed as follows:

```
edges1 = DeleteCases[Join[UndirectedEdge @@@ edges0, UndirectedEdge @@@ shared] /.drules, UndirectedEdge[x_, x_]] // DeleteDuplicates
```

The graph is then (with vertex coordinates included) looks like this:

```
vcs = <|1 -> {191547., 233014.}, 2 -> {191966., 232564.}, 3 -> {192661., 233342.}, 4 -> {192646., 233614.}, 5 -> {192721., 233312.}, 6 -> {192748., 233395.}, 7 -> {192562., 233369.}, 8 -> {192548., 233283.}, 9 -> {192415., 233396.}, 10 -> {192417., 233499.}, 11 -> {192898., 233187.}, 12 -> {192872., 233114.}, 13 -> {192291., 232735.}, 14 -> {192787., 233115.}, 15 -> {192656., 232349.}, 16 -> {192523., 232499.}, 17 -> {192018., 232551.}, 18 -> {192031., 232433.}, 19 -> {192319., 232974.}, 20 -> {192012., 232568.}, 21 -> {192800., 231560.}, 24 -> {193266., 232889.}, 30 -> {192211., 232583.}, 31 -> {192221., 232395.}, 38 -> {192321., 233414.}, 39 -> {193709., 232561.}, 46 -> {192688., 233328.}, 56 -> {192257., 233418.}, 60 -> {192509., 233283.}|>

Graph[edges1, VertexCoordinates -> vcs, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

For larger examples (these can be 10^5 edges or more) the `NestList` function is by far the slowest step. I haven't been able to come up with a faster or better method, any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Update:*** A faster and cleaner version:

```
drule3 = Alternatives[##2] -> # & @@@ ConnectedComponents[shared];

edges3 = UndirectedEdge @@@ (edges0 /. drule3);

edges3 == edges1
```

> ```
> True
> ```

**Original answer:**

```
drules2 = Flatten[Thread[{##2} -> #] & @@@ ConnectedComponents[shared]]; // 
  RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.000072984
> ```

versus OP's `drules`:

```
drules = Reap[NestWhile[
    DeleteDuplicates[Rest[#] /. Sow[Rule @@ Reverse[First[#]]]] &,
    shared, Length[#] > 0 &]][[2, 1]] // 
   DeleteCases[Rule[x_, x_]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.00110268
> ```

```
drules2 == drules
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
edges2 = UndirectedEdge@@@DeleteCases[x_ -> x_][Join[edges0, shared] /. drules2];

Graph[edges2, VertexCoordinates -> vcs, VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: that's pretty elegant and fast, thanks very much! It looks like I'd implemented a clunky version of what ConnectedComponents does.